# Algorithm to Copy data faster than windows default copy provider

Tags: c++, algorithms

I need an algorithm which can copy data(files/folder) from one place to another, faster than windows default copy/paste option. I'm working in vc++. Is there any algorithm by which I can do copy/paste faster.
Or *Is there is any other suggestion to perform this task?*
Thanks

Comment: Other suggestions would require us to understand your problem. So far you have only given us your idea of a solution. So how about you explain the problem. Why do you think this is a solution?

Comment: @andy256, Actually I'm not getting how to do this task. some Apps are there like `tera copy` and `xcopy` which says they do copy/paste work than windows default copy. By Other suggestion I mean is there any library (is case algo is not there) to do this.

Comment: It would be interesting if you add the examples you mention in your comment to the question's formulation.

Comment: Your problem is not well defined. How much faster are you looking to copy? What are you copying (lots of small files, lots of large files, single/few large files, directory structures?). Simplistically speaking, there is no faster algorithm than reading the data and writing it somewhere else. That said, you can parallelize, you can map your inputs and outputs to memory pages for faster access, you can (probably) write your code to avoid page swaps, and so on. The correct solution would depend on some details (wich you have not provided).

Comment: @utnapistim I want to make a program in VC++ which can copy large data(files and folders more than 3-4 GB) from 1 directory to another and file transfer should be faster than windows copy program. that is my problem. I'm not getting how to do it.

Comment: Again, what's the purpose of the copy/paste? If it's truly at a file level there's probably not too much to be done as copies are quite dominated by read/write time, not an algorithm per se. But ultimately you likely want to do something with this copy. Depending on your use case, we might be able to suggest something faster, perhaps something like a copy-on-write strategy or some such. But faster file copying is probably not a goal you want to shoot for as Windows already has a fast general purpose method, and I just don't there's that much flexibility.

Comment: @JTrana I want to make application like `tera copy` or `xcopy` which can copy any type or size of file faster.

Comment: Your question suffers from a fundamental misunderstanding. Copy+Paste is not the way, how files are copied on Windows. C+P is only a UI way to *initiate* the shell's animated copy action. This is something completely different.

Comment: As for your benchmarking needs (for understanding whether there exists a room for improvement), you can compare your speed with the [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) command-line tool on Windows. Also, be sure to test network drives (SMB/Samba), USB drives, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows copy/paste function has several components.

- A cute GUI interface
- Pre-analysis of the work to be done, to help the GUI provide nice feedback and detect conflicts
- Essentially single tasking
- A very fast internal API for copying files.

In my opinion you are unlikely to be able to write code that can beat the Windows CopyFile() API function. You can however use multi-threading to saturate the IO channel and if you also omit the cute GUI stuff and the pre-analysis then that's probably as fast as you can go.

You can test this quite easily by running several XCOPY tasks at the same time and watching the resource monitor to see when you reach the maximum IO throughput.

One final thought: if you're copying a lot of small files there may be advantages in copying files that are located close together to minimise disk head movement. You would need to test to find out whether that is a factor.